# why int can't be compared to null but Integer can be compared to null

Tags: java, integer, int

Though this has been discussed in detail in various forums including `SO` and I have read most of the replies of the experts, But below is the problem is confusing me.

I have few `integer` variables and my requirement is to check `null` before executing few statements. So first I have declared as `int (I don't have knowledge on int and Integer)`.

```
int a,b,c;
if(a == null) {
    //code here
}
```

But complier is not allowing me to declare like this.

After searching in google, experts advised me to use `Integer` instead of `int` and when I changed like the code below

```
Integer a,b,c;
if(a == null) {
   //code here
}
```

This is fine with the compiler as `Integer` is defined as `Object` in java and `int` is not.

Now my code has become some declarations with `int` and some with `Integer`.

Can anyone suggest if declaring `Integer` will give the same result as `int` also can I change all my declarations to `Integer`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a,b,c;
if (a == null) {
    //code here
}
```

This code doesn't make sense, because primitive `int` types cannot be null.  Even if you considered auto-boxing, `int a` is guaranteed to have a value before being boxed.

```
Integer a,b,c;
if (a == null) {
   //code here
}
```

This code makes sense, because Object `Integer` types can be null (no value).

As far as the functionality, the Object vs built-in types actually do make a bit of a difference (due to their different natures).

```
Integer a,b,c;
if (a == b) {
  // a and b refer to the same instance.
  // for small integers where a and b are constructed with the same values,
  // the JVM uses a factory and this will mostly work
  //
  // for large integers where a and b are constructed with the same values,
  // you could get a == b to fail
}
```

while

```
int a,b,c;
if (a == b) {
  // for all integers were a and b contain the same value,
  // this will always work
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Buck for your reply... I don't have any issue while comparing with variable but my application has some functionality that is forcing me to compare with null... Can you advice me on using `Integer` instead of `int` or if there are any issues doing that.

Comment: Using Integer is important when dealing with items that must take a Object.  For example, you can have an ArrayList<Integer> but you cannot have an ArrayList<int>; because, int cannot be cast to an Object, so the `add(T item)` method cannot be implemented.  (as `int` is not a subclass of `Object`, while `Integer` is).  These days auto-boxing hides most of these distinctions, but occasionally it is still important to understand the differences.

Comment: If I don't deal with objects.. still can I take `Integer`? for storing values and using those for arithematic operations? Thanks for your continous assistance

Comment: `Integer` is an object that wraps an `int`.  If you don't deal with objects, you don't deal with `Integer`s.  You can use whatever you need to use to solve your problem (it doesn't matter which one you use); however, when using some of the already-built-in items, you occasionally need an `Object` even when you really only are dealing with `int`s.  In such a situation you use the `Integer` object that represents the `int` value you would have used.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is the primitive type, and is not a nullable value (it can't ever be null).  `Integer` is a class object, which can be null if it has not yet been instantiated.  Using an `Integer` vs. an `int` won't really affect anything in terms of functionality, and your code would behave the same if you changed "int" to "Integer" everywhere.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder.. Thanks for your reply... So I can change all my declerations from `int` to `Integer` without any loss of functionality.

Comment: Correct.  They would function the same.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder That is, if somebody doesn't come along and do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/christopherperry/7815316) to Integer.

Comment: And the added benefit is now your Integers can either represent an int, or have 'no value' by being set to null. This means you don't have to use a 'magic number' to represent 'no value'.

Comment: Passing around null is not a good idea. I've found [Optional](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) to be more helpful for expressing the intent of my code, and sometimes people swallow exceptional conditions and pass null. Bad habit to do that.

Comment: I disagree - passing null is fine. The perceived problem is usually due to lack of documentation, or laziness in coding eg. calling Map.get() instead of Map.containsKey() to see if there is a stored value.